# Suggestions For Parsing Google SERP Results from a desktop application

Tags: c#

I need to obtain the Google Search Results Ranking (SERP) for keywords + search terms using C#. I know Google provides an Ajax search API for web-based apps. But I need to do it from within a desktop application. Any suggestions about where I should start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope by this time your issues must be resolved.

In my view you can add a service (WCF) project to your solution and using appropriate end points you should be able to consume the Ajax data from Goggle Web Service.

Sanjay Zalke